# I do not know how to animate a component

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I want to animate a `Button` when it is added to a `Form` , which layout manager is a `GridLayout(2,2);` I want that the `Button` is moving downward smoothly before occupying the grid cell area for its position. How to do that animation in LWUIT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the button to the form and don't invoke repaint/revalidate etc. instead invoke `myForm.animateLayout(500);`.

This will only work on 1.5 or newer obviously, you can see samples of this in the animation and layout sections in the LWUIT demo.